# Get other side of association from persistent property

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

I have got two entities:

```
class A{
    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY , mappedBy = "a")
    private List<B> bList;
}
class B{
    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=A.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
    private A a;
}
```

For example I have got "a" persistent property from B class and I need to retrieve the other side of association - "bList" persistentProperty of A class. But I don't know the name of the other side property. How could I do that? Association obverse property is null every time. And I don't want to use doWithProperties() method and check fields for equality by class, because there are might be some other properties with the same class.

I was trying to make something like this:

```
PersistentEntities persistentEntities;
Class aClass = A.class;
Class bClass = B.class;
PersistentProperty<?> obverse = persistentEntities.getPersistentEntity(bClass).getPersistentProperty("a").getAssociation().getObverse();
```

But it is null every time. Maybe I am missing something. Thanks for help!

Comment: I'd say it's `"A_ID"`. It should be the opposite side's identifier of the object. Since I have no JPA project in front of me and I've been fixing some weird code last few months, I can't quite make a check if I'm right.

Comment: `"A_ID"` is the column name of B entity.